# PrimeFaces Datatable always selecting the first element

Tags: jsf, primefaces, composite-component

Every time I select some of the elements of my `p:datatable` it always returns the first one, always.

I have this following **piece of code** that is used on my screen, in which the *detailEntity* is referenced in the table as a row of the same.

## Tab Lots

```
        <sgv:detailCrud
            scrollable="true"
            scrollHeight="350"
            updateClass="lotChangeListener, .crudButtons"
            controller="#{productLotsController}"
            btnDetailDeleteLabel="#{productByLotsController.inNewMode or productLotsController.inNewMode ? productsBundle.deleteLabel : productsBundle.inactivateLabel}"
            withDelete="#{productLotsController.showEntity and productLotsController.deletableEntity}"
            disabled="#{not (productByLotsController.byLots and not productsController.inViewMode)}">
            <p:column headerText="#{productsBundle.productLotsBarcode}">
                <h:outputText
                    value="#{detailEntity.barcode}"
                    converter="barcodeConverter" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="#{productsBundle.productLotsNumber}">
                <h:outputText value="#{detailEntity.number}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column
                headerText="#{productsBundle.productLotsExpiration}"
                rendered="#{productByLotsController.perishable}">
                <h:outputText value="#{detailEntity.expirationData.expiration}">
                    <f:convertDateTime
                        type="both"
                        locale="#{currentUserConfigController.locale}" />
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column
                headerText="#{productsBundle.fieldLabelStockAvailable}"
                rendered="#{productsController.hasStockByLocation()}">
                <h:outputText value="#{productLotsController.getStockByLocation(detailEntity).totalizedStockData.availableAmount}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column
                headerText="#{productsBundle.fieldLabelStockReserved}"
                rendered="#{productsController.hasStockByLocation()}">
                <h:outputText value="#{productLotsController.getStockByLocation(detailEntity).totalizedStockData.reservedAmount}" />
            </p:column>
            //THIS BUTTON ONLY SELECT THE FIRST ROW OF MY TABLE, IT'S BROKEN.
            <p:column
                width="35"
                rendered="#{productByLotsController.byLots}">
                <p:commandButton
                    id="btnPrintPaperLot"
                    title="#{productsBundle.btnPrintBarCode}"
                    process="@this"
                    actionListener="#{printerSelectorController.onPrint()}"
                    icon="fa fa-print">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener
                        value="PAPER"
                        target="#{printerSelectorController.type}" />
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener
                        value="#{productLotsController.getTypePrintedProductLot(detailEntity)}"
                        target="#{printerSelectorController.value}" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
```

As you can see, I have a custom component that I created called `sgv:detailCrud`. He is responsible for owning the CRUD architecture of my services, being able to delete, create or view details of a line. (VIDEO DETAILS)

## Details CRUD Component

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:composite="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">
<head>
<title>Details CRUD Component</title>
</head>
<body>
    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="style" />
        <composite:attribute name="styleClass" />
        <composite:attribute name="listStyle" />
        <composite:attribute name="listStyleClass" />
        <composite:attribute name="datailStyle" />
        <composite:attribute name="datailStyleClass" />
        <composite:attribute
            name="controller"
            required="true"
            type="eprecise.sgv.server.core.CrudController" />
        <composite:attribute
            name="disabled"
            default="false" />
        <composite:attribute
            name="withInsert"
            default="true" />
        <composite:attribute
            name="scrollable"
            default="false" />
        <composite:attribute
            name="scrollHeight"
            default="400" />
        <composite:attribute
            name="withDelete"
            default="true" />
        <composite:attribute
            name="withUpdate"
            default="true" />
        <composite:attribute
            name="emptyMessage"
            default="#{detailCrudBundle.emptyMessage}" />
        <composite:attribute
            name="btnNewLabel"
            default="#{detailCrudBundle.btnNewLabel}" />
        <composite:attribute
            name="btnDetailDeleteLabel"
            default="#{detailCrudBundle.detailBtnDelete}" />
        <composite:attribute
            name="btnDetailSaveLabel"
            default="#{detailCrudBundle.detailBtnSave}" />
        <!-- Parametro de classe Css listener de update -->
        <composite:attribute
            name="updateClass"
            default="#{cc.id}ChangeListener" />
        <composite:facet name="list" />
        <composite:facet name="details" />
    </composite:interface>
    <composite:implementation>
        <p:outputPanel
            id="#{cc.id}"
            styleClass="#{cc.id}ChangeListener">
            <p:panel
                styleClass="Wrapper"
                rendered="#{not cc.attrs.controller.showEntity}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <composite:renderFacet name="title" />
                    <p:commandLink
                        id="btnNew"
                        styleClass="Fright"
                        update="@(.#{cc.attrs.updateClass},.#{cc.id}ChangeListener)"
                        process="@this"
                        icon="fa fa-plus-circle"
                        disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabled}"
                        rendered="#{cc.attrs.withInsert}"
                        action="#{cc.attrs.controller.onBtnNovoClick()}">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle Fs23 White"></i>
                    </p:commandLink>
                    <p:tooltip
                        for="btnNew"
                        showDelay="500"
                        value="#{cc.attrs.btnNewLabel}" />
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </f:facet>
                <p:dataTable
                    id="list"
                    selectionMode="single"
                    scrollable="#{cc.attrs.scrollable}"
                    scrollHeight="#{cc.attrs.scrollHeight}"
                    selection="#{cc.attrs.controller.entity}"
                    emptyMessage="#{cc.attrs.emptyMessage}"
                    value="#{cc.attrs.controller.dataModel}"
                    reflow="true"
                    var="detailEntity"
                    rowKey="#{detailEntity.id}">
                    <f:attribute
                        name="styleClass"
                        value="#{cc.attrs.listStyleClass} #{cc.attrs.styleClass}" />
                    <p:ajax
                        event="rowSelect"
                        listener="#{cc.attrs.controller.onEntityClick()}"
                        process="@this"
                        update="@(.#{cc.attrs.updateClass}, .#{cc.id}ChangeListener, .formConfirmDialog)"
                        onstart="crudController.blockTable();"
                        onsuccess="crudController.unblockTable();" />
                    <composite:insertChildren />
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:panel>
            <p:panel
                id="detailCrudPanel"
                styleClass="disableFluidForButtons detailForm"
                rendered="#{cc.attrs.controller.showEntity}">
                <f:attribute
                    name="styleClass"
                    value="#{cc.attrs.datailsStyleClass} #{cc.attrs.styleClass} detailForm" />
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:commandButton
                        id="btnSaveDetail_#{cc.id}"
                        styleClass="saveBtn RaisedButton Fright WidAuto"
                        update="@(.#{cc.attrs.updateClass}, .#{cc.id}ChangeListener)"
                        process="@(.detailForm)"
                        value="#{cc.attrs.btnDetailSaveLabel}"
                        icon="fa fa-save"
                        rendered="#{cc.attrs.withUpdate and not cc.attrs.disabled}"
                        action="#{cc.attrs.controller.onBtnSalvarClick()}" />
                    <p:commandButton
                        action="#{cc.attrs.controller.onBtnDeleteClick()}"
                        icon="fa fa-trash-o"
                        styleClass="deleteBtn Fright WidAuto"
                        value="#{cc.attrs.btnDetailDeleteLabel}"
                        disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabled}"
                        process="@this"
                        rendered="#{cc.attrs.withDelete and (cc.attrs.controller.inEditMode or cc.attrs.controller.inViewMode)}"
                        update="@(.#{cc.attrs.updateClass}, .#{cc.id}ChangeListener)">
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton
                        update="@(.#{cc.attrs.updateClass}, .#{cc.id}ChangeListener)"
                        process="@this"
                        styleClass="cancelBtn Fright WidAuto"
                        icon="fa fa-ban"
                        value="#{detailCrudBundle.detailBtnCancel}"
                        rendered="#{not cc.attrs.disabled}"
                        action="#{cc.attrs.controller.onBtnCancelarClick()}" />
                    <p:commandButton
                        update="@(.#{cc.attrs.updateClass}, .#{cc.id}ChangeListener)"
                        process="@this"
                        styleClass="RedButton RaisedButton"
                        icon="fa fa-arrow-left WidAuto"
                        value="#{detailCrudBundle.detailBtnBack}"
                        rendered="#{cc.attrs.disabled}"
                        action="#{cc.attrs.controller.onBtnCancelarClick()}" />
                    <p:defaultCommand
                        target="btnSaveDetail_#{cc.id}"
                        scope="detailCrudPanel" />
                </f:facet>
                <composite:renderFacet name="details" />
            </p:panel>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </composite:implementation>
</body>
</html>
```

Another detail is that **I can do these crud operations on the rows of the table without any problem, that is, hitting the index**. **However**, I have this problem of always selecting the first row when I click my button to print a lot variation, it's like it doesn't obey the crud architecture for some bizarre reason...

I believe this problem is only for the view, but for the sake of conscience I will post the code of the two controllers of this button here too, follow the thread.

#### Method that should take the selected entity in the table and assemble it from the String Builder

```
public String getTypePrintedProductLot(ProductLot selectedLot) {
        if (selectedLot != null && selectedLot instanceof ProductLot) {
            final Optional<ProductLabelSetting> optional = this.productLabelSettingsRepository.listActives().stream().findFirst();

            if (optional.isPresent()) {
                final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                final HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductLotsController.class);
                log.warn("********** SELECTED LOT NUMBER IN TABLE **********\n");
                log.warn(selectedLot.getNumber());
                log.warn("********** SELECTED LOT NUMBER IN TABLE **********\n");

                params.put("product", selectedLot);

                final ProductLot lot = selectedLot;
                params.put("lot", lot);
                if (lot.getExpirationData() instanceof PerishableExpirationData) {
                    params.put("lotExpiration", sdf.format(lot.getExpirationData().getExpiration()));
                } else {
                    params.put("lotExpiration", "Não Perecível");
                }
                params.put("login", this.currentUser.getLogin().toUpperCase());
                params.put("enterprise", this.currentEnterprise.getName().toUpperCase());
                builder.append(optional.get().parser(params));

                return builder.toString();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

#### Controller that receives the values ​​from the String Builder and prints the variation according to this information

```
package eprecise.sgv.server.core.printers;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import eprecise.sgv.server.products.ProductLotsController;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import eprecise.sgv.server.core.ViewController;
import eprecise.sgv.server.core.auth.Current;
import eprecise.sgv.server.core.util.FacesMessageUtil;
import eprecise.sgv.server.devicesHub.remoteHw.RemoteHwChannel;
import eprecise.sgv.server.devicesHub.remoteHw.printers.RemoteHwPrinter;
import eprecise.sgv.server.devicesHub.remoteHw.printers.RemoteHwPrintersRepository;
import eprecise.sgv.server.users.User;
import org.primefaces.PrimeFaces;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


@ViewController
public class PrinterSelectorController implements Serializable {

    private enum PrintType {
                            COMMON,
                            PAPER,
                            COUPON
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final RemoteHwPrintersRepository repository;

    private final User user;

    private final RemoteHwChannel remoteHwChannel;

    private String id;

    private String value;

    private String type;

    private @NotNull @Min(1) int amount = 1;

    private Boolean withAmount = false;

    private RemoteHwPrinter printer;

    public PrinterSelectorController() {
        this.repository = null;
        this.user = null;
        this.remoteHwChannel = null;
    }

    @Inject
    public PrinterSelectorController(RemoteHwPrintersRepository repository, @Current User user, RemoteHwChannel remoteHwChannel) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.user = user;
        this.remoteHwChannel = remoteHwChannel;
    }

    public void onPrint() {
        if (!this.withAmount) {
            switch (PrintType.valueOf(this.type.toUpperCase())) {
            case COMMON:
                break;
            case PAPER:
                if (this.user.hasDefaultPrinterPaper()) {
                    if (this.print(this.user.getConfigurations().getDefaultPrinters().getPaper())) {
                        FacesMessageUtil.addInfoMessage("Etiqueta impressa com sucesso.");
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    this.showDialog();
                }
                break;
            case COUPON:
                break;
            default:
                this.showDialog();
                break;
            }
        } else {
            this.showDialog();
        }
    }

    public void onPrint(RemoteHwPrinter printer) {
        if (printer != null) {
            switch (PrintType.valueOf(this.type.toUpperCase())) {
            case COMMON:
                break;
            case PAPER:
                if (this.print(printer)) {
                    FacesMessageUtil.addInfoMessage("Etiqueta impressa com sucesso.");
                }
                break;
            case COUPON:
                break;
            }
        } else {
            FacesMessageUtil.addErrorMessage("Nenhuma impressora selecionada.");
        }
    }

    public void onPrintSelect() {
        this.onPrint(this.printer);
    }

    private boolean print(DefaultPrinter defaultPrinter) {
        final Optional<RemoteHwPrinter> optional = this.repository.findById(defaultPrinter.getId());

        if (optional.isPresent()) {
            return this.print(optional.get());
        }

        this.showDialog();
        return false;
    }

    private boolean print(RemoteHwPrinter printer) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.value)) {
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 1; i <= this.amount; i++) {
                builder.append(this.value);
            }
            this.remoteHwChannel.sendPrint(printer, builder.toString());

            this.clearFields();

            return true;
        }

        FacesMessageUtil.addErrorMessage("Modelo a ser impresso está vazio.");
        return false;
    }

    private void clearFields() {
        this.amount = 1;
        this.printer = null;
        this.id = null;
        this.value = null;
        this.type = null;
    }

    private void showDialog() {

        final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PrinterSelectorController.class);
        log.warn("********* VALUE OF SELECTED LOT *********\n");
        log.warn(this.value);
        log.warn("********* VALUE OF SELECTED LOT *********\n");

        PrimeFaces.current().executeScript(
                new StringBuilder("PF('").append(this.id).append("_").append("listPrintersDialogJs").append("').show();").toString());
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return this.amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public RemoteHwPrinter getPrinter() {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(this.type)) {
            return null;
        }
        switch (PrintType.valueOf(this.type.toUpperCase())) {
        case COMMON:
            break;
        case PAPER:
            if (this.user.hasDefaultPrinterPaper()) {
                final Optional<RemoteHwPrinter> optional = this.repository
                        .findById(this.user.getConfigurations().getDefaultPrinters().getPaper().getId());
                if (optional.isPresent()) {
                    this.printer = optional.get();
                }
            }
            break;
        case COUPON:
            break;
        }

        return this.printer;
    }

    public void setPrinter(RemoteHwPrinter printer) {
        this.printer = printer;
    }

    public Boolean getWithAmount() {
        return this.withAmount;
    }

    public void setWithAmount(Boolean withAmount) {
        this.withAmount = withAmount;
    }
}
```

###### Details

I'm using Java 8 with primefaces in version 7

###### Some images

[image: Broken primefaces table]
[image: Details of correct index selected (LOT NUMBER 3)]

###### Video

https://youtu.be/kw_xhQxrV-M

Comment: Why do you give the id btnPrintPaperLot to that button? Can you post also a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), maybe a GitHub link of a small project with your problem?

Comment: @WoAiNii I unfortunately can't give you a reproducible example, this project isn't actually mine, and it has a lot of dependency to make this screen appear, but any additional detail whether in text or video I can manage without problems. About the id I just put a text that represents the button, can there be some kind of conflict?

Comment: Since that button is in the last column of that data table, it's repeated for every row, but it should have a unique id. You should check also the ids of your list, since is used as rowKey, to check that every row has its own value.

Comment: Understood. I tried this, putting the buttom with id "btnPrinterPaperLot_#{detailEntity.id} but no success, i saw at the DOM of this screen these buttons, there aren't with the same id, it's something like

mainForm:j_idt288:j_idt583:list:0:btnPrintPaperLot_

mainForm:j_idt288:j_idt583:list:1:btnPrintPaperLot_

mainForm:j_idt288:j_idt583:list:1:btnPrintPaperLot_

They have a difference by id of the table

About the rowKey, i checked and every member has its own unique value, the hashcode and equals of my entity use its value too.

Comment: At the moment I solved the bug by circumventing it, I placed the print button inside the detailed entity instead of leaving it as a column in the p:datatable